# Parsing date expression patterns using ML

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

From [the Natty website](http://natty.joestelmach.com/):

> Natty is a natural language date parser written in Java.  Given a date expression, natty will apply standard language recognition and translation techniques to produce a list of corresponding dates with optional parse and syntax information.

For example, with input strings like the below:

```
13/08/1993
23/09/2016
24/12/1992
...
13-08-1993
23-09-2016
24-12-1992
...
13-Sep-1993
23-Sep-2016
24-Dec-1992
...
Some other formats
```

Natty [parses the input](http://natty.joestelmach.com/doc.jsp) into abstract syntax trees (AST) to produce a list of corresponding dates that are standardised in format. [Try it out!](http://natty.joestelmach.com/try.jsp)

**Question**: Can ML methods be used to perform this task?

Specifically, let us assume that this is a supervised learning task, with some annotated output strings corresponding to the normalised date strings of the input date expression. e.g. output of `23/01/2016` or `23 jan 2016` or `23rd jan 2016` is `Sat Jan 23 2016`.

With enough annotated data, can a "model" be "trained" to produce such outputs? Some issues:

1. I understand that unlike traditional ML tasks, this is neither a "traditional" classification nor a regression task.
2. However, perhaps we can "classify" a date string into one of the many possible dates? (For this, perhaps we can have a constraint that there are no times, only dates, and a earliest and latest possible date as bounds to make the output discrete in nature)
3. Alternatively, perhaps we can perform regression with [string metrics](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/String_metric) as a measure of string similarity between input and output? With this approach, can traditional gradient descent methods be used to minimise a loss function defined as the string-dissimilarity between the input and output strings?

Comment: Look into seq2seq architecture, that can solve this type of problems in supervised setting, Maybe you can try character level seq2seq or maybe mixture or word/character encoder-decoders

Comment: To expand chiragjn's comment: an example of seq2seq task of transcribing date formats can be found on deeplearning.ai Coursera course (Sequence models). The course also covers the appropriate theory.